# EF Core - One-to-many and Many-to-one relationship on same pair of entities

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have problem defining relationship between two entities.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

1. I wish to have some kind of media file (video/image/file) with user
   comments.
2. User comments can also have multiple media files.

I'm using .net core 3.1 and latest EF Core

**Classes:**

```
 public class Comment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // can belong to media file but in future this comment could also belong to say.. 
    // feed post, some other in-app activity
    public Guid? ParentMediaId { get; set; }
    public virtual MediaFile ParentMedia { get; set; }

    // can contain multiple media
    public virtual ICollection<MediaFile> CommentMediaCollection { get; set; } = new HashSet<MediaFile>();
}

public class MediaFile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // this media file can belong to comment, but also number of other entities in app
    public Guid? ParentCommentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment ParentComment { get; set; }

    // can also have multiple comments
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new HashSet<Comment>();
}
```

**Configuration files:**

Comment configuration file

```
            builder
            .HasMany(x => x.CommentMediaCollection)
            .WithOne(x => x.ParentComment)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentCommentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder
            .HasOne(x => x.ParentMedia)
            .WithMany(x => x.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentMediaId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
            .IsRequired(false);
```

Media configuration file:

```
            builder
            .HasOne(x => x.ParentComment)
            .WithMany(x => x.CommentMediaCollection)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentCommentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
            .IsRequired(false);

        builder
            .HasMany(x => x.Comments)
            .WithOne(x => x.ParentMedia)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentMediaId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

**Problem:**

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Comment.ParentMedia' of type 'MediaFile'. 
Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using 
the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Followed number of suggestions online but all boil down to configuration which to me... seems fine?

Cheers!

Comment: I wonder if a comment should have a media file. Shouldn't a comment be simply that, a comment?

Comment: Well I'm imagining being able to respond to say a picture with a comment and two pictures for that comment. Like say on facebook

Answer (score 0):

> 1.I wish to have some kind of media file (video/image/file) with user comments.
>
> 2.User comments can also have multiple media files.

From your requirement,you need to configure a many-to-many relationship.

Here is a working demo:

1.Model:

```
public class Comment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //other properties

    public virtual ICollection<CommentMediaFile> CommentMediaFiles { get; set; } 
}

public class MediaFile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //other properties

    public virtual ICollection<CommentMediaFile> CommentMediaFiles { get; set; } 
}
public class CommentMediaFile
{
    public Guid CommentId { get; set; }
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
    public Guid MediaFileId { get; set; }
    public MediaFile MediaFile { get; set; }
}
```

2.DbContext:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MediaFile> MediaFiles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CommentMediaFile>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.CommentId, t.MediaFileId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CommentMediaFile>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Comment)
            .WithMany(p => p.CommentMediaFiles)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.CommentId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CommentMediaFile>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.MediaFile)
            .WithMany(t => t.CommentMediaFiles)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.MediaFileId);
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Comment: I mean yes I considered that but how should I know which media file does the comment belong to if that comment also contains some media file. I should distinguish parent one and just plain media files that belong to comment. Image commenting picture on facebook with 2 pictures..

Comment: Take this implementation like you wrote it for example...then I would solve having parent media file by adding the IsParentMedia flag for example in the join table perhaps? But how would that make sure that I only have 1 parent per 1 unique comment. So 1 comment 1 parent media.. but 1 parent media N comments but also 1 comment N plain media files